# Is Haskell Platform 7.10.2-a1 missing documents?

Tags: macos, haskell, haskell-platform, haddock

I installed **Haskell Platform 7.10.2-a1 64bit-signed.pkg** on a MacBook Pro running OS X 10.11.1.

It brought up a nice display in Safari. When I click on 'Libraries' and the 'Codec.Compression.Zlib', i get a page of  `Safari can't find the file` with the url `file:///Library/Haskell/ghc-7.10.2-x86_64/lib/zlib-0.5.4.2/doc/html/Codec-Compression-Zlib.html`

I searched the output of "ghc-pkg" and found a bunch more missing, including `vector`, `syb`, `split`, `parsec`, `parallel`, `QuickCheck` -- 42 in all.

What did I do wrong?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Answer applies to version 7.10.3.)

You didn’t do anything wrong.

Yes, the [Haskell Platform 7.10.3 64bit.pkg](https://haskell.org/platform/download/7.10.3/Haskell%20Platform%207.10.3%2064bit.pkg) installer really is missing HTML Haddock documentation for all non-GHC packages. You can quickly verify this by opening up the installer, choosing File > Show Files (⌘I), and searching for `Data-Text.html`; the only result will be `.../src/Data-Text.html`, which is just the prettyprinted source code (produced by hscolour), not the Haddock documentation.

I'm not sure why the documentation is missing from the official packages. As a workaround you could do your own build of Haskell Platform. When I tried it, it worked for me, and all the documentation was there.

```
git clone https://github.com/haskell/haskell-platform.git
cd haskell-platform
git checkout tags/7.10.3
curl -OL http://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.10.3/ghc-7.10.3-x86_64-apple-darwin.tar.xz
./platform.sh ghc-7.10.3-x86_64-apple-darwin.tar.xz
```

After several minutes, the package ended up in the `build/product` directory.